How can I enable a .crx extension in Chrome?
I coded an extension for Chrome, packed it as crx via Chrome, and loaded it in Chrome. How can I enable it? The enable button is greyed out, clicking on it does nothing.

I use Chrome Version 125.0.6422.77 (Official Build) (64-bit) + Win10.
The extension works fine if I load its code (not the crx) as an unpacked extension.

Google disabled the ability load extensions the way you describe 11 years ago. What you want isn’t possible. Suppose you can try this but you haven’t provided enough information to answer your question

@Ramhound Thanks, the crx extension does load. But it is disabled. Which info should I add?

Try putting the extension id in the field in the screenshot

@Ramhound Thank you, I have just tried that, the enable button is still greyed out :(

You created the registry key?

@Ramhound yes https://i.sstatic.net/IYq9e12W.png


How can I enable a .crx extension in Chrome?

It is not possible anymore to enable a .crx extension in Chrome.
